# mongoDB rolling upgrade 5.0 to 6.0 service impacted

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

my app seems to be impacted during rolling upgrade mongoDB 5.0 to 6.0 community and it seems the impact was caused during shard members restarts , in mongos logs those messages appeared:

```
 {"t":{"$date":"2024-01-25T23:42:57.217+01:00"},"s":"I", "c":"QUERY", "id":4625501, "ctx":"conn573535","msg":"Unable to establish remote cursors","attr":{"error":{"code":40414,"codeName":"Location40414","errmsg":"BSON field 'DatabaseVersion.timestamp' is missing but a required field"},"nRemotes":0}}
 {"t":{"$date":"2024-01-25T23:42:57.383+01:00"},"s":"I", "c":"QUERY", "id":4625501, "ctx":"conn573498","msg":"Unable to establish remote cursors","attr":{"error":{"code":40414,"codeName":"Location40414","errmsg":"BSON field 'DatabaseVersion.timestamp' is missing but a required field"},"nRemotes":0}}
 {"t":{"$date":"2024-01-25T23:42:57.530+01:00"},"s":"I", "c":"QUERY", "id":4625501, "ctx":"conn573550","msg":"Unable to establish remote cursors","attr":{"error":{"code":40414,"codeName":"Location40414","errmsg":"BSON field 'DatabaseVersion.timestamp' is missing but a required field"},"nRemotes":0}}
```

Please, advice how I can avoid service down times during such an upgrade?

P.S.

After mongoses restarts service recovered , but I was expecting the service to not be impacted at all during rolling upgrades as described in the official procedure  ...

Comment: How do you connect to your `mongos`? Of course, if you connect only to one `mongos` and this one is restarted, then you have an interruption. If you connect to several `mongos`, then the running command should simply re-run. Did you set server parameter [mongosShutdownTimeoutMillisForSignaledShutdown](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/parameters/#mongodb-parameter-param.mongosShutdownTimeoutMillisForSignaledShutdown)? Default is 15 seconds which could be a bit short - depending on your application. An of course, you must restart the `mongos` one-be-one and not at the same time.

Comment: the problem appear when shard members have been restarted , and finally disappear after all 8x mongoses restarted  afcourse one by one ...

Comment: Did you wait some time till shard replica set members had been synchronized? For `mongod` you may set parameter `shutdownTimeoutMillisForSignaledShutdown` which also defaults to 15 seconds. The last time when I upgraded to MongoDB version 7 it took half a day. Don't rush when you upgrade your cluster, take your time and wait for fully restart and synchronization.

Comment: I did 1-2min between every member ...